# Why does Flutter android.build.gradle.task Failded to read Keystore from its location

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a WebView app in flutter using VS code. I tried to sign the app bundle, but I gets error message as:-

> **Failed to read key upload from store "C:\Users\USER\keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available**<

I have android SDK **android-28**, **android-29**, **android-30**, android-31 in my computer location **(C:\Java\andr-sdk\platforms)**, and **28.0.3**, **29.0.2** and **31.0.0** in location **(C:\Java\andr-sdk\build-tools)**

So please can someone look at my work and tell me why I get the error message. or how best to sign my app bundle.

I generated my keystore with the following:-

> **(keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks**)

and the keystore has been used to upload app in google play store. Now I want to produce an update version with this project.

In my **gradle.build** file I have the following:-

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

    android {
     
     compileSdkVersion 30
     buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        
    }
      ====================
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.companyname.myappname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.2"
        multiDexEnabled true 

    }

       signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

my **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
```

my **key property**

```
storePassword=mypasswoed
keyPassword=mypassword
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=C:\\Users\\USER\\keystore.jks
```

my **main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter WebView',
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isLoading = true;

  late WebViewController webView;

  Future<bool> _onBack() async {
    var value = await webView.canGoBack();

    if (value) {
      await webView.goBack();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onBack(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://mywebsite.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageStarted: (url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                  });
                },
                onPageFinished: (status) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
                  webView = controller;
                },
              ),
              isLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 20.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                      child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ))
                  : Stack(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your username on your pc?

Comment: @Ahmad Hassan My username on my pc is "MAX". Does it has to do with the file path? the path is as this ....Local Disk(C:) > Users > USER > keystore.jks . Where will my username comes in?

Comment: Yup refer to my answer it will work, if any issue comes let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I've found the issue with your keystore path you are giving its wrong. Your username is MAX so you have to put your username there instead of USER. Replace the last line of your key.properties file with this code

```
storeFile=C:/Users/MAX/keystore.jks
```

Make sure you have this key in the same directory as well, head to `C:\Users\MAX` there it should be a file named keystore.jks if its there then the above line will work super file and you will be able to sign your app just fine. Another thing that is recheck the name of the file you made for adding reference to the keystore file on your local machine I'm talking about the `key.properties` file make sure its spelled correctly and its exact `key.properties` not anything else like `key.property` and it should be in android folder of your flutter project.

I'm also seeing that you have put your keyAlias name as upload but if the file under your username `C:\Users\MAX` is upload.jks then just change your storeFile file name as

```
storeFile=C:/Users/MAX/upload.jks
```

but if the file there is named as keystore.jks then you have to change your keyAlias to `keyAlias=keystore` instead of `keyAlias=upload`

Also a bonus for you here's a good software to explore jks files you can get sha1 sha256 fingerprints easily from it here's the link to it [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/).

Happy Fluttering!